# Extract text outside of a HTML Tag

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class=example>Text #1</div> "Another Text 1"
<div class=example>Text #2</div> "Another Text 2"
```

I want to extract the Text outside the  tag, "Another Text 1" and "Another Text 2"

I'm using JSoup to achieve this.

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the next `Node` (not `Element`!) of each `div`-tag. In your example they are all `TextNode`'s.

```
final String html = "<div class=example>Text #1</div> \"Another Text 1\"\n"
                  + "<div class=example>Text #2</div> \"Another Text 2\" ";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("div.example") ) // Select all the div tags
{
    TextNode next = (TextNode) element.nextSibling(); // Get the next node of each div as a TextNode

    System.out.println(next.text()); // Print the text of the TextNode
}
```

Output:

```
 "Another Text 1" 
 "Another Text 2"
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to  use the `ownText()` method (see the Jsoup [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29)). This method returns the text owned by the specified element only, and ignores any text owned by its direct children elements.

Using only the html that you provided, you could extract the `<body>` owntext:

```
String html = "<div class='example'>Text #1</div> 'Another Text 1'<div class='example'>Text #2</div> 'Another Text 2'";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
System.out.println(doc.body().ownText());
```

Will output:

```
'Another Text 1' 'Another Text 2'
```

Note that the `ownText()` method can be used on any `Element`. There's another example in the [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29).