# JSOUP Parsing between closed tags

Tags: android, html, parsing, tags, jsoup

I'm using jSoup to parse a HTML, but the text I am looking for is not enclosed inside a tag. For example:

```
<strong>Album:</strong> Picasso Biggie <em>|</em>
```

So the text I am trying to parse is the album "Picasso Biggie"
How can I do this in jSoup?

I haven't found a solution even after going through the cookbooks.
If it's not possible in jSoup is there another HTML parser that can do this?

---

**Solved:**
Followed the instruction from [Extract text outside of a HTML Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883691/extract-text-outside-of-a-html-tag)

Comment: probably duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813821/jsoup-parsing-invalid-html-with-unclosed-tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract text outside of a HTML Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883691/extract-text-outside-of-a-html-tag)

Comment: Thanks, this should get me on the right track.